# paste only part of a vector according to a T/F colum

Tags: r, string, gsub

Let's pretend I have a data frame with species that display colors.

```
df<-data.frame(name=paste("spec",1:5),
         ind=c("blue;green","red","green","red;green;blue",""))
```

And **some** (blue and red) of the colors actually mean something. I can just `grepl()` them and get a T/F-column

`df$isredorblue<-grepl("blue|red",df$ind)`

But now I want to know *which* of the *meaningful* colors were displayed in a column.

The desired result is:

```
> df
    name            ind isredorblue searchcolor
1 spec 1     blue;green        TRUE        blue
2 spec 2            red        TRUE         red
3 spec 3          green       FALSE       other
4 spec 4 red;green;blue        TRUE    red;blue
5 spec 5                      FALSE       other
```

I have tried gsub with a [^]+ but that doesn't really work because it matches *all* the letters so "r" or "e" or "d" not "red"...

```
>     gsub("[^red]+","",df$ind)
[1] "eree"    "red"     "ree"     "redreee" ""
```

And now I'm thinking of using strsplit... but can't seem to figure out my next step(s)

```
blabla<-strsplit(df$ind, split=";") 


blabla<-blabla[-which(!blabla %in% c("red","blue"))]

> blabla
[[1]]
[1] "red"
```

Please keep in mind this is a *reprex*, my actual data frame is a lot larger and there are different indicators "colors" that matter for different things so I need to be able to produce these columns in as few steps as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches.

1. Using regex -

This creates a regex pattern from `color` to extract from `ind` column in the data. If there is no value extracted we replace the blank with `'other'`.

```
color <- c('red', 'blue')
pat <- paste0(color, collapse = '|')
df$is_color_present <- grepl(pat, df$ind)
df$searchcolor <- sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$ind, pat), paste0, collapse = ';')
df$searchcolor[df$searchcolor == ''] <- 'other'
df
#    name            ind is_color_present searchcolor
#1 spec 1     blue;green             TRUE        blue
#2 spec 2            red             TRUE         red
#3 spec 3          green            FALSE       other
#4 spec 4 red;green;blue             TRUE    red;blue
#5 spec 5                           FALSE       other
```

2. Without regex using `tidyverse` -

We get the data in long format splitting on `;` and keep only those values which is present in `color`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(ind, sep = ';') %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(is_color_present = any(ind %in% color), 
            searchcolor = paste0(ind[ind %in% color], collapse = ';'), 
            searchcolor = replace(searchcolor, searchcolor == '', 'other'))
```

Comment: I used the regex version... just fyi, it throws a warning... "Error: 'st_exctract_all' is not an exported object from 'namespace:stringr'"

Comment: Yes, I think it is missing `r` in `str_extract_all`

Comment: yup ;-), that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

First define all the target colors as a vector:

```
targets <- c('red', 'blue')
```

Now use the vector, transformed into a regex alternation pattern, to extract the wanted colors in a new column:

```
df %>%
   mutate(colors = str_extract_all(ind, paste0(targets, collapse = "|")))
    name            ind    colors
1 spec 1     blue;green      blue
2 spec 2            red       red
3 spec 3          green          
4 spec 4 red;green;blue red, blue
5 spec 5
```

If you have many color names, some of which may share the same letters (such as "red" and "darkred"), you may want to wrap word boundaries around the color names:

```
df %>%
  mutate(colors = str_extract_all(ind, paste0("\\b(",paste0(targets, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")))
```

Here's another `dplyr` solution (not the most concise though):

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    blue = ifelse(grepl("blue", ind), "blue","other"),
    red = ifelse(grepl("red", ind), "red","other"),
    target = ifelse(blue=="blue"|red=="red", paste(red, blue), "other"),
    target = sub("^other\\s(?=blue|red)|(?<=blue|red)\\sother$", "", target, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-c(3:5))
    name            ind   target
1 spec 1     blue;green     blue
2 spec 2            red      red
3 spec 3          green    other
4 spec 4 red;green;blue red blue
5 spec 5                   other
```

Data:

```
df<-data.frame(name=paste("spec",1:5),
               ind=c("blue;green","red","green","red;green;blue",""))
```